# Metro Bundler ready. ERROR ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-start

Metro Bundler ready.

ERROR  ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have solved it by running following command.

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

then

```
sysctl --system
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are not interested in the technical details and only want to get Listen to work:**

If you are running **Debian, RedHat, or another similar Linux distribution**, run the following in a terminal:

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

If you are running **ArchLinux**, run the following command instead (see here for why):

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/40-max-user-watches.conf && sudo sysctl --system`

**Then paste it in your terminal and press on enter to run it.**

***More info:** [https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers_)*